# How to sort xy coordinates to get a continuous polygon

Tags: python, numpy, polygon

I have two arrays with `(x, y)` coordinates:

```
xx = np.array([513, 512, 508, 507, 506, 505, 504, 503, 502, 501, 500, 498, 497,
       492, 492, 488, 487, 482, 482, 480, 480, 479, 479, 478, 478, 477,
       477, 476, 476, 475, 475, 474, 474, 473, 473, 472, 472, 471, 471,
       470, 470, 469, 469, 468, 468, 467, 467, 466, 466, 465, 465, 464,
       464, 462, 462, 461, 461, 460, 460, 459, 459, 458, 458, 457, 457,
       455, 455, 454, 454, 453, 453, 452, 452, 451, 451, 450, 450, 449,
       449, 448, 448, 447, 447, 446, 446, 445, 445, 444, 444, 443, 443,
       442, 442, 441, 441, 440, 440, 439, 439, 438, 438, 437, 437, 436,
       436, 437, 437, 436, 436, 437, 437, 436, 436, 437, 437, 438, 438,
       439, 439, 440, 440, 441, 441, 443, 443, 448, 449, 451, 452, 453,
       454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 463, 464, 474, 475, 479, 480, 483,
       484, 488, 489, 490, 491, 498, 499, 503, 504, 515, 516, 521, 522,
       532, 533, 538, 539, 549, 550, 561, 562, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569,
       570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 578, 579, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588,
       589, 590, 594, 595, 605, 606, 607, 611, 612, 619, 620, 621, 622,
       623, 624, 628, 629, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 643,
       644, 654, 655, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 669,
       670, 671, 682, 683, 687, 688, 689, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705,
       706, 707, 708, 709, 713, 714, 724, 725, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733,
       734, 735, 736, 737, 739, 740, 745, 745, 747, 747, 748, 749, 751,
       752, 757, 757, 759, 759, 760, 760, 761, 761, 762, 762, 763, 763,
       764, 764, 763, 763, 762, 762, 761, 761, 760, 760, 759, 759, 758,
       758, 757, 757, 756, 756, 755, 755, 753, 753, 748, 747, 744, 744,
       739, 738, 736, 735, 734, 733, 732, 731, 725, 724, 722, 721, 718,
       718, 713, 712, 710, 709, 708, 707, 706, 705, 704, 704, 699, 698,
       696, 695, 694, 693, 692, 691, 689, 689, 684, 683, 681, 680, 679,
       678, 677, 676, 675, 674, 673, 672, 667, 666, 664, 663, 662, 661,
       660, 659, 658, 657, 656, 652, 651, 650, 649, 648, 647, 646, 645,
       644, 641, 640, 638, 637, 636, 635, 634, 633, 629, 628, 626, 625,
       624, 623, 622, 621, 614, 613, 611, 610, 609, 608, 607, 606, 600,
       599, 597, 596, 595, 594, 593, 592, 591, 590, 589, 587, 585, 584,
       582, 581, 580, 579, 578, 577, 576, 575, 574, 571, 570, 569, 567,
       566, 565, 564, 563, 562, 561, 560, 559, 556, 553, 552, 550, 549,
       548, 547, 546, 545, 544, 544, 539, 538, 536, 535, 534, 533, 532,
       531, 530, 529, 528, 524, 523, 658, 659, 669, 670, 674, 675, 676,
       677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 684, 685, 691, 691, 693, 693, 694,
       694, 695, 695, 696, 696, 697, 697, 698, 698, 697, 697, 696, 696,
       695, 695, 694, 694, 693, 693, 691, 691, 685, 684, 682, 681, 680,
       679, 678, 677, 676, 675, 674, 670, 669, 659, 658, 654, 653, 652,
       651, 650, 649, 648, 647, 646, 644, 643, 637, 637, 635, 635, 634,
       634, 633, 633, 632, 632, 631, 631, 630, 630, 631, 631, 632, 632,
       633, 633, 634, 634, 635, 635, 637, 637, 643, 644, 646, 647, 648,
       649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 518, 519, 529, 530, 534, 535, 536,
       537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 544, 545, 551, 551, 553, 553, 554,
       554, 555, 555, 556, 556, 557, 557, 558, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566,
       567, 568, 569, 570, 572, 573, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581,
       582, 583, 584, 586, 587, 592, 593, 595, 596, 602, 602, 604, 604,
       605, 605, 606, 606, 607, 607, 608, 608, 609, 609, 610, 610, 611,
       611, 610, 610, 609, 609, 608, 608, 607, 607, 606, 606, 604, 604,
       598, 597, 595, 594, 593, 592, 591, 590, 589, 588, 587, 583, 582,
       572, 571, 570, 566, 565, 559, 558, 554, 553, 546, 545, 544, 543,
       542, 541, 537, 536, 526, 525, 521, 520, 519, 518, 517, 516, 515,
       514, 513, 511, 510, 504, 504, 497, 497, 495, 495, 494, 494, 493,
       493, 492, 492, 491, 491, 490, 490, 491, 491, 492, 492, 493, 493,
       494, 494, 495, 495, 496, 496, 495, 495, 494, 494, 493, 493, 492,
       492, 491, 491, 490, 490, 491, 491, 492, 492, 493, 493, 494, 494,
       495, 495, 497, 497, 503, 504, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512,
       513, 514])

yy = np.array([168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 171, 171, 172, 172, 173, 173, 175, 175,
       180, 181, 185, 185, 190, 191, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199,
       200, 201, 205, 206, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 220,
       221, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 235, 236,
       237, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 251, 252, 253,
       255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 267, 268, 270, 271,
       272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 283, 284, 295, 296, 300,
       301, 311, 312, 316, 317, 328, 329, 333, 334, 345, 346, 350, 351,
       361, 362, 367, 368, 378, 379, 384, 385, 395, 396, 400, 401, 402,
       403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 410, 411, 416, 416, 418, 418, 419,
       419, 420, 420, 421, 421, 422, 422, 423, 423, 422, 422, 421, 421,
       420, 420, 419, 419, 418, 418, 417, 417, 416, 416, 415, 415, 416,
       416, 415, 415, 416, 416, 415, 415, 414, 414, 413, 413, 412, 412,
       411, 411, 410, 410, 409, 409, 408, 408, 407, 407, 406, 406, 405,
       405, 404, 404, 403, 403, 404, 403, 403, 402, 402, 401, 401, 400,
       400, 399, 399, 398, 398, 397, 397, 396, 396, 395, 395, 394, 394,
       393, 393, 394, 394, 395, 395, 396, 396, 397, 397, 398, 398, 400,
       400, 399, 399, 398, 398, 397, 398, 398, 399, 399, 400, 400, 401,
       401, 402, 402, 403, 403, 404, 404, 403, 403, 402, 402, 401, 401,
       400, 400, 399, 399, 397, 397, 392, 391, 389, 388, 387, 387, 385,
       385, 380, 379, 377, 376, 375, 374, 373, 372, 371, 370, 369, 365,
       364, 354, 353, 349, 348, 347, 346, 345, 344, 337, 336, 332, 331,
       330, 329, 328, 327, 326, 325, 324, 322, 321, 316, 316, 313, 312,
       307, 307, 305, 305, 304, 304, 303, 303, 297, 297, 295, 295, 292,
       291, 286, 286, 284, 284, 283, 283, 282, 282, 281, 280, 275, 275,
       273, 273, 272, 272, 271, 271, 269, 268, 263, 263, 261, 261, 260,
       260, 259, 259, 258, 258, 257, 257, 252, 252, 250, 250, 249, 249,
       248, 248, 247, 247, 246, 246, 245, 245, 244, 244, 243, 243, 242,
       242, 239, 239, 237, 237, 236, 236, 235, 235, 231, 231, 229, 229,
       228, 228, 227, 227, 220, 220, 218, 218, 217, 217, 216, 216, 210,
       210, 208, 208, 207, 207, 206, 206, 205, 205, 204, 204, 202, 202,
       200, 200, 199, 199, 198, 198, 197, 197, 196, 196, 195, 195, 193,
       193, 192, 192, 191, 191, 190, 190, 189, 189, 186, 186, 184, 184,
       183, 183, 182, 182, 181, 180, 175, 175, 173, 173, 172, 172, 171,
       171, 170, 170, 169, 169, 168, 316, 315, 315, 316, 316, 317, 317,
       318, 318, 319, 319, 320, 320, 322, 322, 328, 329, 331, 332, 333,
       334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 343, 344, 354, 355, 359, 360, 361,
       362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 369, 370, 376, 376, 378, 378, 379,
       379, 380, 380, 381, 381, 382, 382, 383, 383, 382, 382, 381, 381,
       380, 380, 379, 379, 378, 378, 376, 376, 370, 369, 367, 366, 365,
       364, 363, 362, 361, 360, 359, 355, 354, 344, 343, 339, 338, 337,
       336, 335, 334, 333, 332, 331, 329, 328, 322, 322, 320, 320, 319,
       319, 318, 318, 317, 317, 316, 217, 216, 216, 217, 217, 218, 218,
       219, 219, 220, 220, 221, 221, 223, 223, 229, 230, 232, 233, 234,
       235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243, 243, 244, 244, 245, 245,
       246, 246, 247, 247, 249, 249, 251, 251, 252, 252, 253, 253, 254,
       254, 255, 255, 257, 257, 262, 262, 264, 264, 270, 271, 273, 274,
       275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 285, 286, 290, 291, 295, 296,
       306, 307, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 321, 322,
       328, 328, 330, 330, 331, 331, 332, 332, 333, 333, 334, 334, 335,
       335, 334, 335, 335, 336, 336, 337, 337, 338, 338, 339, 339, 340,
       340, 341, 341, 342, 342, 341, 341, 340, 340, 339, 339, 338, 338,
       337, 337, 335, 335, 329, 328, 321, 320, 318, 317, 316, 315, 314,
       313, 312, 311, 310, 306, 305, 295, 294, 290, 289, 288, 287, 279,
       278, 274, 273, 272, 271, 269, 268, 267, 266, 265, 264, 263, 262,
       261, 260, 256, 255, 245, 244, 240, 239, 238, 237, 236, 235, 234,
       233, 232, 230, 229, 223, 223, 221, 221, 220, 220, 219, 219, 218,
       218, 217])
```

Actually, it looks like this :

[image: Plot]

My problem: I need a single polygon (coordinates) that consider both inner holes as well. Using 3 polygons (for outer and inner contour) won't work in my case. My idea was to use sort the (x,y) coordinates by using the closest Euclidean distance. However, this approach won't be able to jump from one contour to the next one. Here outlined in red is the desired output (gaps were drawn larger for visual purposes):

[image: Desired output]

Ideally, the area (marked in green) should be maximised. Thus, the criteria to jump from one contour is based on the closed distance to avoid area loss (see below)

[image: Maximise the area between outer and inner contour]

---

**Update:**
Thanks to kaya3 for the suggestion with MST:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import mistree as mist


mst = mist.GetMST(x=xx, y=yy)
d, l, b, s, l_index, b_index = mst.get_stats(include_index=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

# plotting nodes:
plt.scatter(xx, yy, s=10, color='r')

# plotting MST edges:
plt.plot([xx[l_index[0]], xx[l_index[1]]],
         [yy[l_index[0]], yy[l_index[1]]],
         color='k')

plt.xlim(0, 700)
plt.ylim(0., 700)
plt.xlabel(r'$X$', size=16)
plt.ylabel(r'$Y$', size=16)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Incorrect output (not all contours are connected after applying MST):
[image: MST output]

Comment: What should be the criteria that causes the program to "jump" from the outer shape to one of the inner holes? With my human eye, I see no distinction. (With my lizard eye is another story...)

Comment: Very good question, I edited my original post and hope it is clear now. Thanks for your question.

Comment: There are no areas "marked in green" in either of the images.

Comment: @martineau Please refresh the page and the green area should be visible.

Comment: In a sense what you want to do is similar to the graphics technique called [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) — so I suspect there may be some way to adapt that relatively simple approach to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @martineau thanks for your input. From my understanding of flood fill, it is only useful if I want to measure the area. However,  I am not interested in the area but what I need is a single polygon list with (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: That's what I meant about it adapting it to what you're doing. It's not about measuring the area, it's about finding connected regions (usually of pixels). That's not the output you want, so some way of turning then into polygons would be needed. You might even be able to find some image-processing module that does something like that. It become an image to vector problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Thus, the criteria to jump from one contour is based on the closed distance ...

This is the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). It is a well-studied NP-complete problem, and there is no known solution which is both efficient and gives exact answers. However, for your case, a "good enough" answer should do, so you can consider [heuristic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms). There are many well-known heuristics which you can find information about via Wikipedia or other sources.

I think a good solution for your use case would be to start with a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST), which should look like your solution except with just one edge bridging the separate parts rather than two. From there, you should be able to add a second edge to each bridge going the other way, and connect any small gaps in the polygonal parts caused by the tree not finishing off the cycles.

For your example, the red lines in the image below show an MST, and the yellow lines are the edges you would need to add to make it into a cycle. Hopefully it's clear that finding the MST makes this problem a lot simpler.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I have tried MST as you suggested but can't find all the bridges. I have updated the original post.

Comment: The image you added shows a disconnected graph, so either there is a mismatch between the data formats used by the MST algorithm and the graph-drawing code, or a bug in the code that draws the graph, or a bug in the MST algorithm (not likely, since it's from a widely-used library). An MST is by definition connected, so if it's not connected then it's not an MST.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem. I think it makes sense to first connect the three contours into three separate, closed polygons, one outer *P*, and two inner, *A* (larger, left) and *B* (smaller, right). And only then consider the shortest "bridge" connecting the inner polygons 
either to each other (as you have drawn *B* connected to *A*) or to the outer *P*. Note that if you use the shortest segment connecting *B* to either *A* or *P*, it will connect to *P* (as *B* curves quite close to *P*). And, moreover, the bridge you show between *A* and *P* is not the shortest bridge:
rather a North-West bridge is shorter.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. In principle, I have the coordinate lists for each contour (from cv2.findcontours. However, I think your suggestion may work for 1 object but in my case I have around 20 objects (I just chose 1 to simplify the problem).